# How to save a 2dmap obtained from a topic published by octomap?

Tags: ros, octomap, map-saver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Octomap provides a projected 2d map through the topic "projected_map". I want to save this map. The map server is also running. So i remapped the topic in the octomap server launch file :

This info is given in the ros wiki:
map (up to fuerte) / projected_map (since fuerte) (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid)

```
Downprojected 2D occupancy map from the 3D map. Be sure to remap this topic if you have another 2D map server running. New / changed in octomap_mapping 0.4.4: The topic is now projected_map by default to avoid collisions with static 2D maps
```

I am able to visualise in rviz but when i try to save it :

**rosrun map_server map_saver -f mapName**

The default map is saved rather than the map from octomap.

Any suggestion what is wrong ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74617/how-to-save-a-2dmap-obtained-from-a-topic-published-by-octomap-??/) by [kk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5289/kk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2013-08-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to remap `map:=projected_map`, when saving.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5289/kk/) on 2013-08-25**:
Thank you very much.